# Import Stripe subscriptions into Commerce 3

Tags: craft3, import, stripe, plugin-craftcommerce3

Is there a straight-forward way to import Stripe subscriptions into Commerce 3? I had hoped FeedMe or similar would do it, but it seems not: https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/472

Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm looking to do the same thing... Did you find out an answer for this by any chance?! Thanks so much in advance, Ella

Comment: Craft are hoping to release this as an update to Commerce in the next month or so, if you can hold on :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft are hoping to release this as an update to Commerce in the next month or so!